# Removing outlier with multiple consecutive values similar to a step

Tags: matlab, data-science, signal-processing, outliers

I am processing an ocean wave data, where I have a timeseries of the Peak Wave Period (Tp (s)). The typical values for Tp ranges from 2s-15s for this location. However, it may reach higher values above 15s during extreme events such as a storm. Hence, removing data based on a threshold value is not suitable.

As you can see in the figure below, there are multiple values that are outliers. The high values occurred for a small duration and then dropped down. An extreme event would last for hours.

I have tried the functions `filloutlier` and `medfilt1`, but they are not successful in removing the outlier, which I presume is because multiple consecutive outlier data points exists.

Is there a built-in Matlab function exist to handle such situation?
Else, if I need to write my own function to filter such signals, could you provide some guidance.

Attaching a small data sample here as well: [Download Data](http://www.speedyshare.com/drive/s/GNUwVV8vMuULgH3hWKgo0pzc6HYf8I)

Dataset plot (Only the segment in the provided data above)
[image]

Zoomed in plot at one of the outliers.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. If we know that we need the values to be in the range of (2,15), we can clip the values > 15 to 15.
2. Another way is to use the value of a high percentile (say 95) of the observations and clip values about it.

`filloutlier`, `medfilt1` methods are not removing values like 18 because they are not treating them as outliers. 18 is not very far away from the typical range of (2, 15).

Comment: Thank you. The reason I can not use a threshold value to clip the dataset is it is possible to have high Tp values during a storm event. However, it wont be a a sudden increase (<15min duration as the outliers here) and would last for over 1-2 hours with slow ramp up.